# How to show that the function is concave when second derivative is inconclusive ?

Tags: optimization

How can I show that the following function $f(\lambda)$ is concave for $\lambda \geq hz_1 + \sigma^2$ ?

$f(\lambda) = 1- \exp(\frac{hz_1 + \sigma^2 - \lambda}{z_1b}) + \exp(\frac{hz_0+\sigma^2-\lambda}{z_0b})$

where $z_1 > z_0$, $b>0$ and $\sigma^2 >0$.

Comment: I have considered the second derivative test, but can't figure how to prove the second derivative $\leq 0$.

Comment: could you show your work on the second derivative?

Comment: The second derivative comes w.r.t $\lambda$ comes to be

Comment: The second derivative w.r.t $\lambda$ comes to be $f''(\lambda) = -\frac{1}{z_1^2 b^2}\exp (\frac{hz_1 + \sigma^2 - \lambda}{z_1 b}) + \frac{1}{z_0^2 b^2}\exp (\frac{hz_0 + \sigma^2 - \lambda}{z_0 b})$. I have plotted the original function against $\lambda$ and it is strictly concave for $\lambda \geq hz_1+\sigma^2$. I have also plotted the second derivative for this range of $\lambda$ and it is all negative. I just need help with proving it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\begin{align}
f''(\lambda) &= -\frac{1}{z_1^2 b^2}\exp (\frac{hz_1 + \sigma^2 - \lambda}{z_1 b}) + \frac{1}{z_0^2 b^2}\exp (\frac{hz_0 + \sigma^2 - \lambda}{z_0 b}) \\
&> -\frac{1}{z_0^2 b^2}\exp (\frac{h}{b} + \frac{\sigma^2 - \lambda}{z_1 b}) + \frac{1}{z_0^2 b^2}\exp (\frac{h}{b} + \frac{\sigma^2 - \lambda}{z_0 b}) \\
&= \frac{1}{z_0^2 b^2}\left( \exp (\frac{h}{b} + \frac{\sigma^2 - \lambda}{z_0 b})- \exp (\frac{h}{b} + \frac{\sigma^2 - \lambda}{z_1 b}) \right)
\end{align}
$

The first factor is positive, so the second factor needs to be positive as well for $f''(\lambda)>0$, which translates to:

$$
\exp (\frac{h}{b} + \frac{\sigma^2 - \lambda}{z_1 b}) > \exp (\frac{h}{b} + \frac{\sigma^2 - \lambda}{z_0 b})
$$
$$
\frac{\sigma^2 - \lambda}{z_1 b} > \frac{\sigma^2 - \lambda}{z_0 b}
$$
Since $\lambda > \sigma^2$, and $z_1 b > z_0 b$, this is indeed valid. So, the function is convex for $\lambda > \sigma^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This helps.